# Show that $(b_n)$ is strictly increasing iff the function $b:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an injection.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

*Suppose that $(b_n)$ is an increasing sequence.* Show that $(b_n)$ is strictly increasing iff the function $b:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an injection.

**My proof**

$[\implies]$ if $(b_n)$ is strictly increasing then $(b_n)\lt(b_{n+1}) \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Which implies that $b_n\neq b_{n+1}$ when $n\neq n+1$.

$[\impliedby]$ if a function is injective then $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, n\neq n+1 \implies b_n\neq b_{n+1}$. *Which implies $b_n\lt b_{n+1}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.*.

$\square$

Can you please comment on my attempt? I think everything, but the last sentence has a sound arguments.

Comment: DId you leave out some assumption like $b_{n+1}\ge b_n$ for all $n$?  Because $b_n=1/n$ looks injective but not strictly increasing.

Comment: This is false.  $b(n) = -n$ is injective and $(b_n)_n$ is strictly decreasing.  $b(n) = (-1)^n n$ is injective and neither increasing nor decreasing.

Comment: sorry folks, I've added the assumption that $(b_n)$ is an increasing sequence. Hence it (1) can't be $b_n = b_{n+1}$ because it's injective, (2) is can't be  $b_n\gt b_{n+1}$ because if the assumption {that I've forgot to add in the original statement}, so it must be (3) $b_n\lt b_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $(\Longleftarrow)$ part of the  statement is not true.

Take $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$ which is an injection,but is strictly decreasing.

The proof of the   $(\Longrightarrow)$ part of the statement is correct.

Since  you changed the assumption from just ''sequence''  to ''an increasing sequence'' then it is true if you add some more context in your proof.

Comment: And if you think about $b_n=(-1)^n\frac1n$, it doesn't even need to be monotone.

Comment: Foks, sorry. So given the assumption that $(b_n)$ is increasing does it make my $(\impliedby)$ part correct?

Comment: @u1731182 i edited

Comment: @u1731182... Also when you ask a question,then do not change the assumption after an asnwer  is posted because then the answer it gets nullified and downvoted..so you must add the assumption not change it completely.

Comment: sorry again. I didn't realise that assumption was a breaking point. Now I see ... by the number of down votes.

Comment: @u1731182 i believe so,but i did not downvote though